# C3P0 connection pool reported ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded error

Tags: oracle, hibernate, c3p0

I am working with the Hibernate 3.6  and c3p0-0.9.2-pre1. I am getting Exception ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded error while using the C3p0 configurations in the hibernate.cfg.xml.

I have a Oracle's DatabaseSchema.conf file in which I have around 200 create table statement, while validating that Oracle’s Database Schema, I encountered a weird scenario:

1. If I did not use connection pooling, then no problem, once closed Connection, database released the opened cursors, and open_cursors count did not increased significantly, it will remain under default open_cursors count i.e 300.
2. But if we used connection pooling, then open_cursors count increased significantly and crosses the default open_cursors count i.e 300 and reported exception ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded error.

I have already tried the following approaches :

1. Set the value to '0' of the below properties in hibernate.cfg.xml, In order to disable the statement cache of the C3p0.
               property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements"
               property name="hibernate.c3p0.maxStatementsPerConnection"
2. After closing SESSION , CONNECTION , RESULTSET assign them NULL.

   ```
   SESSION: 
                   if(session != null && session.isOpen()) {
                       session.close();
                       session = null; //assign null
                   }

    RESULTSET :
                    if(rs != null) {
                       rs.close();
                       rs=null;  //assign null
                   }

    CONNECTION :
               if(conn != null) {
                  conn.close();
                 conn=null;  //assign null
                }
   ```
3. Used Various Permutation and Combination in configuration of  C3P0 defined in the hibernate.cfg.xml

Ex:  Subsequently Increased the numHelperThreads and observed the OPEN_CURSOR count, changed the pool’s min and max size. In similar way I have changed the other configurations also.

5. Used the Connection Provider class in the C3P0 configuration and imported the hibernate-c3p0 jar compatible with the Hibernate 3.6.
6. Upgraded the Hibernate version from 3.6 to 5.2.
7. Used the DBCP Connection Pooling Mechanism instead of the C3P0.

Approaches from 1-6 results in the High OPEN_CURSOR counts and Only Approach 7 results in the desired outcome.

What else should I tried to work with the C3P0?

Comment: What is the version of your Oracle JDBC driver? (Note: the number in the driver's file name is **not** the driver version, it's the intended Java version)

Comment: do you have any code that is outside of the hibernate framework that is opening and (maybe not closing) cursors?  use "select * from v$open_cursor" to see which sql is being left open

Comment: 1) what is your pool size? one way this could happen is just more parallelism than your DB supports. if you set `hibernate.c3p0.max_size` to a low value, does the problem persist? 2) you really want to be sure that your application is `close()`ing `ResultSet`s and `Statement`s promptly, not just in some end-of-thing, if they are not nulls catch-alls. use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for all of these resources.

Comment: (also, please consider upgrading to c3p0-0.9.5.2 rather than using a prerelease version.)